# How to get previous shutdown cause?

Tags: unix, shutdown

I try to get previous shutdown cause and when it happened but i don't know correct syntax.

```
syslog -k Sender kernel ???
```

I need to get date and time in start of the row and shutdown cause number in end of the row which can be negative number too.

Answer (score 3):

I usually just run

```
sudo grep "Previous shutdown cause" /var/log/system.log
```

or (if the above returns empty)

```
sudo zgrep "Previous shutdown cause" /var/log/system.log.*.gz
```

Comment: syslog should be system.log on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

In Sierra, use log:

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage CONTAINS "shutdown cause"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run *Console.app* (e.g. from *Launchpad*) and in *All messages* and type *shutdown cause* in *Search* box, this will list all codes in a row.

After selecting multiple rows, they can be copied into the clipboard.