# My Mac restarts after logging in

Tags: mac, kernel-panic

1- I identified the problem as a Kernel Panic at first due to warnings

2- Safe Mode Crashes

3- I reinstalled a OS through utilities , problem still persists (crashes after login)

4 - On Single user mode i deleted everything on downloads , removed cache and deleted the sleepimage file.

5- Hardware report (Command D at startup) is OK

6-  I cannot upload image because too big but i used the command (on single user mode)  df to see the space and i got

dev/disk1 
(512 blocks) = (234610432)
Used = (57311056)
Capacity = (76%) 
iused  = (22162420) 
ifree= (7163882) 
%iused= (76%)

i tried to follow all the instructions on here

[Can't login because of kernel panic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321544/cant-login-because-of-kernel-panic)

and the Mac still restarts after login , any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help and time.

Edit- Mac factory os is Maverick
Edit 2- If possible i would like to retain at least most of the data.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a hardware issue. Have you tried taking it to Apple service?

Comment: If the crash is **ONLY** after login it *could* be a damaged profile. Any way to creat another profile? You could then copy your needed files between the two...

Comment: @SteveChambers i created a new admin profile using single user mode , still crashes.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee i will take it to an apple service as of today now that i cannot find any solutions. Kindly thank you both for the help.